# Inno setup: Extract XML node and show it

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following code and I want to extract it into a plain text but I cannot manage to do it.

The code works but what I need is to show it in the `ExpandConstant` field.
I have tried several ways but no luck so far.

```
    function LoadValueFromXML(const AFileName, APath: string): string;
    var
      XMLNode: Variant;
      XMLDocument: Variant;  
    begin
      Result := '';
      XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0');
      try
        XMLDocument.async := False;
        XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
        if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
          MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
            XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
        else
        begin
          XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
          XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
          Result := XMLNode.text;
        end;
      except
        MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
    end;

    procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
    begin
      if CurPageID = CustomPageID then
        CustomEdit.Text := LoadValueFromXML('C:\Games\World_of_Tanks_test\WoTLauncher.xml', '//info/patch_info_urls/item');
    end;

   procedure ClienteWot();
    var
      StaticText: TNewStaticText;
    begin
      StaticText := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
      StaticText.Parent := WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
      StaticText.Left := 425;
      StaticText.Top := ScaleY(40);
      StaticText.Font.Style := [fsBold];
      //StaticText.Font.Color := clRed;
      StaticText.Caption := ExpandConstant('Cliente WOT: -->>> Show XML Url <<<---');
    end;
```

Comment: XML format does not know lines. It has nodes. But anyway, are you asking how to get the whole node text, such as `<node>Value</Node>` ?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that, but yes I want the value of that node
<info><patch_info_urls><item>this value</item></patch_info_urls></info>

Comment: Just for being sure if I got your requirement (since I can't imagine the usage of the whole node text). Do you want to get just a value of that node, in your example `this value`. Or the whole node text (which is what I think you're asking) `<info><patch_info_urls><item>this value</item></patch_info_urls></info>` ?

Comment: Only "this value", I don't need the whole node text.

Comment: Well, then the code that you've posted should work to get the first URL of that `patch_info_urls` URL list (assuming the XML we are talking about is many times mentioned in the WOT forum threads; I don't know its format personally).

Comment: Yes, the code works but I'm trying to show it in "Caption" and that's what I don't know how to do it. (the code is this one: http://pastebin.com/skEKa89p)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What is the *Caption* ? Is your question even related to reading from XML then (if the code for reading works) ? Please edit your question and elaborate what is your aim; *extract it into a plain text* is far too broad.

Comment: I edited the first post and title so that you can understand better what I need.Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69026/discussion-between-tlama-and-dexon).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inline a value into a string that can be passed to the [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) function call, you can use e.g. the [`Format`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_format) function:

```
var
  ...
  URL: string;
begin
  ...
  URL := LoadValueFromXML('C:\MyFile.xml', '//node/subnode');
  StaticText.Caption := ExpandConstant(Format('{username} %s', [URL]));
end;
```

The above pseudocode example reads the XML value and assigns the returned value to the `URL` variable. Then it evaluates the inner statement of the second line:

```
Format('{username} %s', [URL])
```

Which inlines the `URL` string value into the given string (in place of `%s`) and produces a string like:

```
'{username} www.example.com'
```

And this string is then processed by the [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) function call (the outer statement) and assigned to the static text caption, which might be e.g.:

```
'MyUserName www.example.com'
```